# JS Office Outlook add-in: get email as a file or just all email data

Tags: javascript, outlook, office365, outlook-addin, office-js

Is it possible to get **whole email as a file or just collect all email data** using office javascript package? I didn't find any similar method in reference:
https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office?product=outlook&version=v1.5 
But it is possible to get all email data (body, cc, etc.) one by one, is it the only way?

I know it is possible to do so using Microsoft Exchange and email id and access token, but I can't share access tokens due to security requirements.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to get all of the data for that item is by using the Microsoft Graph APIs: [Get Message](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/message_get). We provide support for using the REST APIs in Microsoft Graph in Office.js in [Requirement Set 1.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/use-rest-api).

Comment: Adding a bit more information, it is important to keep in mind that Outlook Add-ins are scoped to the single email message they are activated against. They are not scoped to the entire mailbox and therefore can only see one message at a time. If you're looking to access an entire mailbox, Microsoft Graph is the best option.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT I looking for access to single active email only.

Comment: Are you looking for the RAW data (i.e. headers, content, etc.) or only specific components of the email (body, to, from, etc.)?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT raw data. For now, I composing it one by one (header, form, etc) but there are should be better way

Comment: @outlook-web-addins-team To get this I need an access token, Can user get an access token for himself?

Comment: The Outlook REST APIs require a bearer token in the Authorization header. Typically apps use OAuth2 flows to retrieve a token. However, add-ins can retrieve a token without implementing OAuth2 by using the new Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync method introduced in the Mailbox requirement set 1.5 preview. You can pass isRest as a parameter to get a rest compatible access token